# Clang/LLVM Install Within Slackware?

Tags: software-installation, slackware

I would like to install the Clang/LLVM compiler suite within Slackware since I use it as my default C conpiler for my C programming assignments. I am currently building it within a build directory inside `/usr/local/src` (`/usr/local/src/build`) and wish to install it after compiling. I am following the build instructions on the Clang website:

http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

./configure and make are doing what I expect but there are no instructions for `make install` on the clang website at the end. Should I run `make install` and if yes within the build directory or elsewhere? The actual source code is in `/usr/local/src/llvm`. Should I have created the build directory in `/usr/local/bin` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer your question, but you could [use the llvm 2.9 Slackbuild from slackbuilds.org](http://slackbuilds.org/repository/13.37/development/llvm/) for Slackware 13.37 ([general information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slackware#Community-supported_software), [a howto on slackbuilds.org](http://slackbuilds.org/howto/)). I suppose that's the Slackware way (comparable to Arch's PKGBUILD, someone correct me if I'm wrong, please).